# Send access token without using parameter in URL

Tags: codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and Oauth2 (Alex Bilbies library). 
The API is being used by my iPhone app. For every request I need to send along the access token as a parameter in the URL. Is there a way to send the token in a header instead? To avoid it getting "exposed"?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 3):

OAuth 2.0 bearer tokens allow you to insert them in an HTTP Authorization header as follows:

```
POST /my/api HTTP/1.1
Host: rs.company.com
Authorization: Bearer abcdef123456
```

Where abcdef123456 is your Access Token (see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-16#section-2.1).  In fact the spec says you SHOULD do that in lieu of request parameters if it is possible.

The spec also describes many security considerations when using OAuth 2.0 bearer tokens (see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-16#section-4)

Comment: See last point at http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-16#section-4.3

Answer (score 1):

Sending an access token over GET is just as insecure as sending it in a header.

OAuth 1 used to get around this with all sorts of encryption, secured passwords, hell you could even turn certifications on. This was all a massive ball-ache, so now in OAuth 2 you just have to use HTTPS which does all of this for you.